# Does Apple recover tax paid to government on sales on apps?

Tags: ios-appstore, mac-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

I signed up to sell my apps on the Apple app stores, and the agreement says:

> Apple shall collect and remit to the competent tax authorities the
>   taxes described in Section 3.2 of this Schedule 2 for sales of the
>   Licensed Applications to End-Users located in the following countries,
>   as updated from time to time via the iTunes Connect site:
>
> Albania Australia Austria Belgium Bulgaria Canada China* Croatia
>   Cyprus Czech Republic Denmark Estonia Finland France Germany Greece
>   Hungary Iceland Ireland Italy Latvia Lithuania Luxembourg Malta,
>   Republic of Netherlands New Zealand++ Norway Poland Portugal Romania
>   Slovakia South Africa Slovenia Spain Sweden Switzerland United Kingdom
>   United States

Does Apple recover this tax from me? In other words, will I end up paying more than 30% to Apple when a user from one of these countries buys my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple handles the sales of your app. Technically Apple is the seller, so they collect the taxes. That is why Apple gets 30% of every sold app.

The 70% you get from an app sale are royalties. You only need to add it to your Income Tax.